# How would you join two twin beds?

Tags: furniture, bedroom

I've got two twin beds "joined". There are basically four independent components: two mattresses and two bed bases.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

They are pretty uncomfortable to sleep on. They shift as I move at night. They aren't fixed in any way.

I was thinking of connecting them by a strap. Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00438S56Q), but not that fancy. It would help to solve the upper part. The lower one would still be free and detached.

Do you have any idea how to make this thing stable and interconnected?

Thank you in advance.

---

Update:

It's a rented apartment, and I am not supposed to sell things or change them significantly.

I don't wanna buy new furniture.

Comment: Are the mattresses  moving apart or the frames?

Comment: @Alaskaman Both are. There are 4 independent components.

Comment: You could buy the bed you want and putt those two in storage until you move out.

Comment: Is sleeping on just one of the twin beds an option? There will always be a gap in the middle if you cannot modify the frames and I’d personally rather sleep on a smaller bed than sink into a gap between two beds.

Comment: @statueuphemism it’s terrifying to feel that gap grow at night :) I tried to sleep on one part, it’s too small for me. And you always should keep in mind that there is only one part and you have to lie still in order not to fall down.

Answer (score 2):

What I would ***actually*** do:

**For sale:** two twin beds.

**Want to buy or trade:** one (double, queen, king) bed.

It's the simple solution, it's the right solution, it gets rid of the fundamental problem at a fundamental level.

---

Your pictures do not inform about the bedframes very well. Standard iron frames could be easily conjoined with hose clamps, or bolts, or u-bolts. Wooden frames can be screwed or bolted if you don't mind putting some holes in them.

At the upper level, I vaguely recall some sort of T-pad being sold for the center joint, and it helps immensely if you put on a mattress pad that fits over both beds, as well as sheets that do the same.

Comment: It's a rented apartment, I am not supposed to sell things from it. It's very sound advice, though. I would do that as well.

Comment: Would have helped to provide that information in the question. Don't screw them togther, either, in that case. And look for an apartment with more suitable furnishings for the next one, or an unfurnished apartment and your own furniture... meanwhile, "not as fancy" strap solution could be as easy as a coil of rope and learning some knots, then tie BOTH levels together, all the way around the outside.

Comment: As I found out, the legs are removable and they contribute most to the bed instability. I removed them, the mattresses are now less movable. It's going to be a workaround until I buy straps and tie everything up.

Answer (score 2):

I have that same arrangement. When you strap the mattresses together, the frames will not move any more. The frames only move because when you get an arm or leg in the crack between them the mattresses move apart, then the frames stay with them. Solving the mattress issue solves the frame issue. You can get that strap and cover, but the cover is a pain when you8 go to change the sheets (if you use the twin fitted sheets like I do). I just went to a fabric store and bought two long pieces of webbing strap. They sell buckles there too and I buckle them together.

[image]

You could do it with one long strap, but I thought it would be easier with two. I'm not sure I was right about that though.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll definitely solve the mattresses problem first and see if it helps with the frames.

Comment: “when you get an arm or leg in the crack between the mattresses”, there is ALREADY a crack between the frames which is terrifying at night. It means either you going to wake up and join them back, or you ACCEPT it and continue sleeping on one half :)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko be sure to use a single large fitted sheet over both mattresses instead of two twin sheets

Answer (score 0):

Tie the adjoining legs together with thin rope or thick string?

Comment: Or plastic cable ties.

Comment: The problem is that the legs aren't rigid. When I tie them tightly, they bend slightly.

Comment: Just have to throw in this one - Duct Tape?

Comment: @MichaelKaras yes, duct tape would work if there was no (or a little) distance between the legs

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - You could cut off a length of wood board that just fits between the legs and the wrap the board plus the two adjacent legs with 4 or 5 turns of duct tape.

Comment: ...or lay a piece of plywood or particle board across the gap under the mattresses with rubber non-skid mats above and below the board to keep the frames and mattresses from sliding.